what happens at interim analysis?
I would like to understand what happens rather operationally during/after the interim analysis?

if trial meets prespecified efficacy boundary, the study is unblinded at IA and the results announced publicly? Still safety might be collected for some time? Would efficacy be collected after IA till final?
if trial doesn't meet prespecified efficacy boundary, who does the necessary design adaptations? What is announced to team who conducts the trial? Just that the trial doesn't meet prespecified boundary?


If a pre-specified decision boundary is met at interim, the trial will usually halt: either you don't need more observations to show that the drug's efficacy is at least as good as anticipated (stopping for efficacy), or you are already pretty much certain that the final outcome will not be positive (stopping for futility). You do not have to make these criteria binding, but in both cases continuing the study implies a waste of resources at best.
If your outcome is binary you can make these decisions with full confidence: if you still need more events to show a difference than there's subjects remaining the result is already certain. More often you'd define probability thresholds, stopping when for example the chance of a certain outcome goes below a certain value (e.g. futility if less than 10% chance remains to decide in favour of $H_A$ conditioning on the observed data).
In both cases stopping early means you'd also stop enrolling new subjects and collecting data, usually only completing the follow-up of those ongoing. The decision criteria should be set up in such a way that the comparatively small bits of data that'll still come in would have no meaningful impact on your conclusion.
If you do not stop the study at interim, the ICH E9 guideline is quite clear:

The execution of an interim analysis should be a completely confidential process
because unblinded data and results are potentially involved. All staff involved in the
conduct of the trial should remain blind to the results of such analyses, because of the possibility that their attitudes to the trial will be modified and cause changes in the characteristics of patients to be recruited or biases in treatment comparisons. [..] Investigators should only be informed about the decision to continue or to discontinue the trial, or to implement modifications to trial procedures.

Indeed, there should be little more disseminated than that the trial will continue, possibly with changes to the design: obviously those executing it need to know about that, though such modifications may still hint to the direction of the result...
